# Disadvantages of metasploit Framework for windows

Tags: penetration-test, metasploit

Are there any explicit disadvantages in comparison to running it on a UNIX machine these days?

Comment: One thing is that my AV (I have tried many of them for Metaspoilt) detects it as a threat and halts the installation. I have to disable it but it again detects and quarantines it after installation. Need to add exceptions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For one, it might not work at all. I tried recently(in April 2012) on two Windows machines (7 and 2008 R2), and some aspect of the PostgreSQL setup invariably fails.

I spoke to a Rapid7 account manager about it, and he confirmed that the Windows version is flaky.

He also recommended against using it in a production environment.

Comment: what about Community Edition?

Comment: It's actually the same installer.

Answer (score 3):

I have been using the Windows port of Metasploit for a while now and it is working great. Also, the development team have done a great job in packaging Metasploit for Windows, installing it is a breeze.

However, some Metasploit modules are not supported on the Windows platform, [like sniffer ones](http://seclists.org/metasploit/2010/q1/110) (pSnuffle for example).

Answer (score 1):

I had Metasploit 4.0 installed on my PC and it worked fine no issues.  But, since i have reinstalled windows 7, it is now incapable of installing becuase of the PostgreSQL issue.  I have MySQL installed.  Maybe if Rapid7 gave us the option to use MySQL from install we wouldn't have this problem.

Also Metasploit fails to update on Backtrack 5 and a ton of modules do not work.

Comment: I'm not sure how this responds to the original post.  You seem to say you had a bad experience, but it isn't clear why, or whether that bad experience is likely to occur for anyone other than you.  Is this an explicit disadvantage to running metasploit on windows?